# JFreeChart: Background of chart is overlayed with black

Tags: charts, jfreechart

I created the following Pie Chart:

```
public class MyPieChart extends ChartComposite {

public MyPieChart(Composite parent, int style, CategoryToPieDataset dataset, ProductivityViewCtrl control) {
    super(/* Composite comp */parent,
    /* int style */style,
    /* JFreeChart jfreechart */null,
    /* int width */10,
    /* int height */10,
    /* int minimumDrawW */1,
    /* int minimumDrawH */1,
    /* int maximumDrawW */Integer.MAX_VALUE,
    /* int maximumDrawH */Integer.MAX_VALUE,
    /* boolean usingBuffer */false,
    /* boolean properties */false,
    /* boolean save */false,
    /* boolean print */false,
    /* boolean zoom */false,
    /* boolean tooltips */true);


    ChartFactory.setChartTheme(new StandardChartTheme("JFree/Shadow"));


    String machineName = "Dummy";
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(machineName, // chart title
            createDataset(), // data
            true, // include legend
            true, false);


    this.setChart(chart);
    chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY.brighter());              
    chart.setAntiAlias(true);

    PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.GREEN);

    plot.setInteriorGap(0.04);
    plot.setOutlineVisible(false);

    // Color between the segments
    plot.setBaseSectionOutlinePaint(Color.BLACK);
    plot.setSectionOutlinesVisible(true);
    plot.setBaseSectionOutlineStroke(new BasicStroke(2.0f));

    plot.setLabelFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
    plot.setLabelLinkPaint(Color.WHITE);
    plot.setLabelLinkStroke(new BasicStroke(2.0f));
    plot.setLabelOutlineStroke(null);
    plot.setLabelPaint(Color.WHITE);
    plot.setLabelBackgroundPaint(null);

    plot.setLabelGenerator(new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator("({0}) {2}"));
    plot.setToolTipGenerator(new StandardPieToolTipGenerator("{0}: {2}"));

    plot.setNoDataMessage("No data available");
    plot.setIgnoreZeroValues(true);

}

private static PieDataset createDataset() {
    DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
    dataset.setValue("One", new Double(43.2));
    dataset.setValue("Two", new Double(10.0));
    dataset.setValue("Three", new Double(27.5));
    dataset.setValue("Four", new Double(17.5));
    dataset.setValue("Five", new Double(11.0));
    dataset.setValue("Six", new Double(19.4));
    return dataset;
}
```

When showing this chart I get the following result:
[image]

As you can see the background is not green but black. If you look very closely to the bottom of the chart you can see a 1 pixel green line, so technically the background is drawn but overriten at some point later.

Now let's set the dataset to null, this gives the expected result, the background is green:
[image]

What am I doing wrong, why is the background overwriteen with black if I have a valid dataset?

I've been trying for about two hours now and can't resolve it :/

**SSCCEE:**

The chart is part of a view inside an eclispe RCP where `MyView` is registered under the `ID,` which is also stored in the class `MyView` in the global final variable `ID`.

I create the view witht he following command:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView(MyView.ID);
```

**MyView:**

```
package at.mypackage.views;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;

    import at.mypackage.charts.MyPieChart;


    public class MyView extends ViewPart {

        public static final String ID = "at.mypackage.views.MyView";

        @Override
        public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
            parent.setLayoutData(new FillLayout(SWT.BORDER));
            MyPieChart chart = new MyPieChart(parent, SWT.BORDER);
        }

        @Override
        public void setFocus() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

}
```

**MyPieChart:**

```
package at.mypackage.charts;


import java.awt.Color;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PiePlot;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;
import org.jfree.data.general.PieDataset;
import org.jfree.experimental.chart.swt.ChartComposite;

public class MyPieChart extends ChartComposite {

    public MyPieChart(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(/* Composite comp */parent,
        /* int style */style,
        /* JFreeChart jfreechart */null,
        /* int width */10,
        /* int height */10,
        /* int minimumDrawW */1,
        /* int minimumDrawH */1,
        /* int maximumDrawW */Integer.MAX_VALUE,
        /* int maximumDrawH */Integer.MAX_VALUE,
        /* boolean usingBuffer */false,
        /* boolean properties */false,
        /* boolean save */false,
        /* boolean print */false,
        /* boolean zoom */false,
        /* boolean tooltips */true);

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart("Dummy", // chart title
                createDataset(), // data
                true, // include legend
                true, false);

        this.setChart(chart);
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY.brighter());              

        PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.GREEN);       

    }

    private static PieDataset createDataset() {
        DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
        dataset.setValue("One", new Double(43.2));
        dataset.setValue("Two", new Double(10.0));
        dataset.setValue("Three", new Double(27.5));
        dataset.setValue("Four", new Double(17.5));
        dataset.setValue("Five", new Double(11.0));
        dataset.setValue("Six", new Double(19.4));
        return dataset;
    }



}
```

Comment: It works in JfreeChart using version 1.14.  What version of JFreeChart are you using and can you provide a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)?  Are you trying to create an Eclipse plug-in?

Comment: I'm using jfreechart 1.0.14. It's part of an eclipse application that I took over. I already implemented various StackedBar charts using this API. I'll provide a SSCCE as soon as possible!

Comment: I updated my post with an SSCCEE. Since it is an elcipse RCP it's not 100% self containing but I did my best. I may also try to upgrade my jfreechart version but I'm afraid that it would break something since the aplication I'm working with is under development since a few years now.

Comment: I jsut gote ntoe from my boss that the previous developer adopted jfreechart to work with SWT and that the bug may be in his new implementation.. :(

Comment: If I modify the JFreeChart sample code to include `plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.GREEN);` then it works OK and changes the colour as you would expect it to

Comment: the default sample code doesn't work either for me. It seems like the previous developer tried to make jfreeChart work on swt and didn't finish the job for PieCharts since StackedBarCharts work just fine. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Aside: `Color.LIGHT_GRAY.brighter()` is `Color.white`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling the shadow generator fixed the problem :)

```
plot.setShadowGenerator(null);
```